# How show an AngularJS variable containing code in HTML <pre> or <code> tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Any hint about this? I googled quite a bit but didn't find anything yet..

This code is showing me the variable name instead the code I stored there:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">{{::data.template}}</pre>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular 1 & 2 you should just be able to use handel bars;

```
<pre class="prettyprint">{{data.template}}</pre>
```

You can also bind the data,

Angular 1:

```
<pre class="prettyprint" ng-bind="data.template"></pre>
```

Angular 2:

```
<pre class="prettyprint" [innerText]="data.template"></pre>
```

You can find more info about binding here - https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/introduction-to-data-binding-in-angular-2-versus-angular-1/

Comment: Hey, Have you got a code snipped I can look at, otherwise its hard to tell whats going on?

Comment: Hey found the solution for my second problem: executing prettify within a $timeout function solved! It was a timing issue, solved with $timeout so a cycle refresh..